# An issue with Grails Hibernate join returning too many objects

Tags: hibernate, grails-orm

I've just started with Hibernate an have encountered the following thing:

I have a domain class

```
class Certificate{
    String name
    Vendor vendor
}
```

and a query: `"select cf from Certificate as cf left join cf.vender as vn"`

The strange thing is that this query returns me two objects:
`[Certificate [name=APS, vendor=HP], Vendor [name=HP]]`

while the same query without join returns a single one:
`[Certificate [name=APS, vendor=HP]]`

How do I specify in the first query that I need only `Certificate` to be returned? I thought that `select cf` was enough.

Comment: You probably want left join **fetch** cf.vender

Comment: @JBNizet, you are right, thanks! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want

```
left join fetch cf.vender
```

which will load the certificates with their vendor.